# Full hour hh:ii:ss to decimal

Tags: javascript

How to convert full time to decimal? In the code below the seconds are not being converted.

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
    var arr = t.split(':');
    var dec = parseInt((arr[1]/6)*10, 10);

    return parseFloat(parseInt(arr[0], 10) + '.' + ( dec < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + dec);
}   

console.log( timeToDecimal('00:01:44') ); // 0.01
console.log( timeToDecimal('00:03:36') ); // 0.05
console.log( timeToDecimal('00:30:47') ); // 0.5
console.log( timeToDecimal('10:10:20') ); // 10.16
console.log( timeToDecimal('01:30:58') ); // 1.5
console.log( timeToDecimal('3:22:10' ) ); // 3.36
console.log( timeToDecimal('22:45:48') ); // 22.75
console.log( timeToDecimal('02:00:05') ); // 2
```

Comment: JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZC387/55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the math first then process the result to string

```js
function timeToDecimal(t) {
    var arr = t.split(':').map(Number);    
    return (arr[0] + arr[1]/60 + arr[2]/3600).toFixed(2);
}   

console.log( timeToDecimal('00:01:44') );
console.log( timeToDecimal('00:03:36') ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('00:30:47') ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('10:10:20') ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('01:30:58') ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('3:22:10' ) ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('22:45:48') ); 
console.log( timeToDecimal('02:00:05') );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code never refers to `arr[2]`, so obviously it is not going to do anything with the seconds.

Your approach with constructing a string that looks like a decimal number and then parsing it with `parseFloat` is strange, to say the least. All you need is

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
  const [hh, mm, ss] = t.split(':');

  return +hh + mm / 60 + ss / 3600;
}
```

But you should really use a library for this. With moment, it would be

```
moment.duration('1:30:22').asHours()
```

Comment: Way simpler a my answer using `Array#reduce`